# Google Kubernetes Engine Broadcast Address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-networking

Is there a way to configure a broadcast address on a Kubernetes cluster on Google Compute Engine? I get a subnet and an address range, but broadcast address from the ethernet adapter shows up as 0.0.0.0, and the default broadcast address for the address range does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compute Engine networking](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#quotas_and_limits) doesn't support broadcasting. If you wish, you can post a little bit about your use case and I'll figure out if there is any solution to the issue.

Comment: Sad. I've solved the problem by having a script on loop write the current Kubernetes cluster members to a file, but it's a bit inelegant.